# Unit test failure on building of Jackson-Core Version 2.11.2

Tags: java, jackson-modules

In the process of manually building the jackson-core module using the latest version of 2.11.2 I am encountering an error in the unit tests; which I'm assuming is due to a setting issue on my laptop.

Steps Performed:

1. Java Version -> 1.8
2. clone jackson-core repo
3. `git checkout tags/jackson-core-2.11.2`
4. `mvn package`

Result:

```
[INFO] Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.004 s - in com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReferenceTest
[INFO] Running com.fasterxml.jackson.core.util.ByteArrayBuilderTest
[INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.005 s - in com.fasterxml.jackson.core.util.ByteArrayBuilderTest
[INFO] Running com.fasterxml.jackson.core.util.DefaultIndenterTest
[ERROR] Tests run: 2, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.006 s <<< FAILURE! - in com.fasterxml.jackson.core.util.DefaultIndenterTest
[ERROR] testWithIndent(com.fasterxml.jackson.core.util.DefaultIndenterTest)  Time elapsed: 0.002 s  <<< FAILURE!
org.junit.ComparisonFailure:
expected:<[]
] but was:<[
>
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.util.DefaultIndenterTest.testWithIndent(DefaultIndenterTest.java:32)

[INFO] Running com.fasterxml.jackson.core.util.RequestPayloadTest
[INFO] Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.007 s - in com.fasterxml.jackson.core.util.RequestPayloadTest
[INFO] Running com.fasterxml.jackson.core.util.SeparatorsTest
....
[INFO]
[INFO] Results:
[INFO]
[ERROR] Failures:
[ERROR]   DefaultIndenterTest.testWithIndent:32 expected:<[]
] but was:<[
>
[INFO]
[ERROR] Tests run: 895, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO]
[ERROR] There are test failures.
```

Question:
I was wondering what setting could be wrong on the laptop that is causing the failure in the Unit tests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at their [code](https://github.com/TheRealHaui/jackson-core), specially at the [specific unit test](https://github.com/TheRealHaui/jackson-core/blob/master/src/test/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/util/DefaultIndenterTest.java#L32), they are comparing `\n` as the `Eol`.
I believe the error you are seeing could be related to the OS you are running on as it might differ between them.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I'm guessing they are building on a linux environment while I am building on a windows environment.  I was able to resolve the issue locally by replacing the assert statement with:

`assertEquals(System.getProperty("line.separator"), defaultIndenterThree.getEol());`